# HTML/jQuery finding text in closest <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table with different td's with the same ID, this is my table, in a foreach loop:

```
<td class="AMLLeft" style="display:inline-block; !important">ID:
    <p class="important">${item.id}</p>
</td>
<td align="right" nowrap="true" class="AMLRight">Transaction sum: ${item.sum} ${item.currencyCode}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hiddenRow">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <p>AML ID: ${item.id}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <input type="button" value="Comment" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary commentButton" <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="${item.id}" data-target="#edit-modal">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hiddenRow">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <p>AML Category: ${item.amlClientCategory}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <input type="button" value="Close" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hiddenRow">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <p>Client ID: ${item.clientId}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <input type="button" value="Set Investigate" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hiddenRow">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <p>Status: ${item.status}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hiddenRow">
    <td align="left">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}">
            <p>Comment: ${item.comment}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to find the value of the 2nd rows: `<p class="important">${item.id}</p>`, This is the code I've tried so far, which didn't work:

```
$(".commentButton").on('click', function () {
  var id = $(this).find('p.important').value();
  alert("id is:" + id);
});
```

Any help with this is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried $(this).closest('p.important').val(); BTW your p does not lie within the input.commentButton, so $(this).find('p.important') won't work.

Comment: p does not have value. you can use `text()` or `html()`

Comment: Also note that .value() doesn't exist in jQuery, it's val(), but as @Pekka has pointed out for p elements its text() or html() which works.

Comment: @NEDian I have tried that, I'm getting "undefined" :/

Comment: @Somethingcool123 because you dont have a p with a class important

Comment: @Pekka I think my 2nd row is, <p class="important">${item.id}</p>

Comment: @Somethingcool123 i missed that one.. try `$(this).closest('tr').siblings()..find('p.important').text();`

Comment: @Pekka Well sir, please add an answer to this question and I'll accept it, that was awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Somethingcool123 Or you could use $(this).closest('table').find('p.important').text(); which has the same effect as .closest('tr').siblings().find('p.important') ... See here http://jsfiddle.net/Lx126hax/15/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('p.important').text();
```

try this

Using the button select the `tr` use `siblings()` to get the tr of the p with .important. after getting the `tr` use `.find()` to search for the `p.important` and finally using `.text()` get the value.

Comment: Thanks again, greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".commentButton").on('click', function () {
  var id = $(document).find('p.important').html();
  alert("id is:" + id);
});
```

`this` is your button, which does not contain the item your searching.
`.html` gets the value between the html tags

Comment: This works for getting the value of the 1st rows ID, as far as I can see. What I want to do is getting the ID of the row I'm clicking ( it's a clickable table )