# Finding text of <p> closest row inside a div HTML/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table is built with the same ID's on every row, with a foreach loop. To find the text inside the `<p class="comment"` - I have to specify where ( I want to find the closest one )

My table looks like this:

```
        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table fixed">
                        <tbody id="extend">
                            <tr data-toggle="collapse123" class="clickableRow" nowrap="true" data-target=".demo${item.id}" id="${item.id}">
                                <td class="AMLLeft" nowrap="true">
                                    <label for="important"style="display: inline !important">ID:</label>
                                    <p class="important"style="display: inline !important">${item.id}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" class="AMLRight">
                                    <pre class="thepre">Transaction sum: ${item.sum} ${item.currencyCode}</pre>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p>AML ID: ${item.id}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" nowrap="false">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><input type="button" value="Comment" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary commentButton" <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="${item.id}" data-target="#edit-modal"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p>AML Category: ${item.amlClientCategory}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><input type="button" value="Close" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary closeButton"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p>Client ID: ${item.clientId}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><input type="button" value="Set Investigate" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary investigateButton"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p class="status">Status: ${item.status}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p class="comment">Comment: ${item.comment}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"><p>Transaction sum: ${item.sum} ${item.currencyCode}</p></div>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <div class="collapse123 demo${item.id}"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

I want to find the text of `<p class="comment">${item.comment}</p>` but this time it's inside a `<div>`. I'm not sure how to do this but this is the code I've tried so far:

```
var commentValue = $(this).closest('tr.hiddenRow').siblings().find('p.comment').text();
```

Any help is very appreciated!

I know I've posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667317/html-jquery-finding-text-in-closest-p-tag) but this is different because it's inside a `<div>`, and I can't help myself.

Comment: IDs must be unique! The `align` attribute is obsolete

Comment: why not: `var commentValue = $(this).closest('p.comment').text();`?

Comment: @Thomas I tried that one too, I get nothing

Comment: @Oriol what do you mean?

Comment: On what event is this code being run? To what does the this refer?

Comment: @OliverRadini it's an onclick event, my button is inside the hiddenRow class

Comment: `$(this).find('p').text();` then

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I thought it would be that easy but I'm getting a blank space ( nothing ) when doing so.

Comment: @Somethingcool123 could you please post your original html with the button still in it? it's easier to JSFiddle

Comment: @Thomas edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save people trawling through the comments, the eventual solution is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5nL1e31z/3

---

I believe this achieves what you wanted, and I've tried to break it out so it's clear what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/5nL1e31z/ If it isn't quite right, just let me know and I can update it.

```
$('.test-button').click(function () {

    var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(parentRow).css('background-color', 'red');

    var hiddenRow = $(parentRow).siblings('.hiddenRow');
    $(hiddenRow).css('background-color', 'yellow');

    var commentTextP = $(hiddenRow).find('.comment');
    console.log(commentTextP.text());
});
```

Comment: I'm getting hiddenRow is not defined

Comment: Is that on the fiddle, or on your own code? If it's your own code, it'd be helpful to see exactly how you're trying to implement it, so that we can properly diagnose what's happening.

Comment: now I'm atleast getting something, but it's a " 0 " in the console

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/5nL1e31z/3/ you should now see the comment text in the console as well as in an alert.

Comment: Thank you sir, for struggling towards victory, rep shall be yours!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, thanks for providing extra details

Answer (score 0):

```
var commentvalue = $(this).parent().find('p').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux0a3zsx/

Because the `button` is what `this` refers to and `p` is not inside it

Comment: this is interesting, because the value in my <p> get's deleted when I'm trying to do this, it's like it dissapears

Comment: @Somethingcool123 well your current HTML is not as you described before: I don't see a div with both a button and a <p> attribute in it, they are in different div's altogether. you might want to change how your HTML is generated first

Comment: it wasn't your code who deleted the text in <p>, I have a REST service which i'm calling aswell :D

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this?

```
var text= $(this).closest('.hiddenRow').find('.comment');
```

Comment: Now I have, I'm getting nothing at all once again :/